# Writing JUnit Test for FileUpload Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, junit

I have a Spring controller that is performing a FileUpload. My controller is taking a HTTP request for a multipart file using @RequestParam. My problem is I am not sure how I can write a JUnit test for my controller. I want to pass in a file stored in my src/main/resources and make sure it processes and writes out the content. Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/DefectImport", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody

// Request file from upload explorer as a multipart file
String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
    //LOGGER.info(">>> uploadFileHandler started");

        // Check if file is multipart file
        if (file.getContentType() != null) {
            try {

                Date uploadDate = new Date();
                //LOGGER.info(">>> Date: " + uploadDate);
                System.out.println(uploadDate);

                //Get input stream of the file
                InputStream is = file.getInputStream();

                // Finds the workbook instance for XLSX file
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (is);

                // Return first sheet from the XLSX workbook
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                // Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
                Iterator<Row> ite = sheet.rowIterator();
                //LOGGER.info(">>> Writing Started of file " + file.getOriginalFilename());
                System.out.println("Writing Started of file " + file.getOriginalFilename());

                // Traversing over each row of XLSX file
                while(ite.hasNext()){
                    Row row = ite.next();

                    // For each row, iterate through each column
                    Iterator<Cell> cite = row.cellIterator();
                    while(cite.hasNext()){
                        Cell c2 = cite.next();

                        // Check for different data types and return value
                        switch (c2.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            //LOGGER.info(c2.getStringCellValue() + " ");
                            System.out.print(c2.getStringCellValue() + " ");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(c2))
                            {
                                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                //LOGGER.info(dateFormat.format(c2.getDateCellValue()) + " ");
                                System.out.print(dateFormat.format(c2.getDateCellValue()) + " ");
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                //LOGGER.info(c2.getNumericCellValue() + " ");
                                System.out.print(c2.getNumericCellValue() + " ");
                            }                               
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            //LOGGER.info(c2.getBooleanCellValue() + " ");
                            System.out.print(c2.getBooleanCellValue() + " ");
                            break;
                        default:                            
                        }
                    }
                    //LOGGER.debug();
                    System.out.println();
                }
                is.close();
                workbook.close();
                //LOGGER.info(">>> uploadFileHandler complete");
                System.out.println("Writing finished...");

            } 

            /**
             * Error handling
             */
            /*catch (InvalidFormatException e)
            {

            }*/
            catch (MaxUploadSizeExceededException e)
            {
                return "The file you uploaded is too large";
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fe) 
            {
                System.out.println("File not found");

            } 
            catch (IOException ie) 
            {
                System.out.println("The file you uploaded is not an XLSX file");
            }       
        }           

        return  "Thank you for your submission!";
    }

}
```

How would I go about writing a test case? Is it possible to do this without using Mock? Could I expose it as a component and have it either accept an fileinputstream or file from request param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to test the uploading of the file. The point at which you likely want to test is that the controller receives the file and processes the file correctly. For this I recommend mocking and serving from a resources directory.

When writing tests always try to follow the given, when, then model. For example:

```
@Test
public void uploadFileTest() throws Exception{
    //given
    InputStream uploadStream = UploadControllerTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("exceldocument.xlsx");
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", uploadStream);
    assert uploadStream != null;

    //when
    this.mockMvc.perform(fileUpload("/DefectImport")
            .file(file))
    //then
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

This mocks the multipart upload of the file and checks that the InputStream is not null and that the status of the upload is ok (200).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The only thing is now inplace of perform() we need to use MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart() now as perform() is deprecated.